# How to retrieve current date and day_of_month from date in hsqldb for listing upcoming birthdays

Tags: java, hsqldb, dayofweek, date

I am trying to retrieve birthdays from list of Dates stored in hsqldb so that i can list upcoming birthdays in next 7 days.
 Below is the query. I am getting unexpected token for curdate when i execute this query. I tried sysdate() and current_date also, I get the same error. please help me resolve this.

```html
SELECT * 
FROM  contacts
WHERE  DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob) YEAR) 
            BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first use of INTERVAL is incorrect syntax. You can modify it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  contacts
WHERE  DATE_ADD(dob, (CURDATE() - dob) YEAR)
            BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```